# the order by clause, there is no country_name in the locations table, how can the parents query order by country_name?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, scalar

```
desc locations

Name           Null?    Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
LOCATION_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(4)    
STREET_ADDRESS          VARCHAR2(40) 
POSTAL_CODE             VARCHAR2(12) 
CITY           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) 
STATE_PROVINCE          VARCHAR2(25) 
COUNTRY_ID              CHAR(2)      

desc countries

Name         Null?    Type         
------------ -------- ------------ 
COUNTRY_ID   NOT NULL CHAR(2)      
COUNTRY_NAME          VARCHAR2(40) 
REGION_ID             NUMBER       

select country_id, city, state_province
from locations l
order by(select country_name
         from countries c 
         where l.country_id=c.country_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order by clause uses a correlated subquery. For each row that's selected, the country name is selected according to the matching IDs, and then the query is ordered by that.

An arguably more elegant way of writing this query is with a `join`, which may be a tad more intuitive:

```
SELECT   l.country_id, city, state_province
FROM     locations l
JOIN     countries c ON l.country_id = c.country_id
ORDER BY c.country_name
```

Comment: @XiaomengSu Happy to help. If this answer helped you, you should consider upvoting or accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Join tables and then apply ORDER BY:

```
select l.country_id, l.city, l.state_province
from locations l join countries c on c.country_id = l.country_id
order by c.country_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT L.COUNTRY_ID, CITY, STATE_PROVINCE 
FROM LOCATIONS L 
INNER JOIN COUNTRIES 
ON COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID = L.COUNTRY_ID 
ORDER BY COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME
```